# Objective C, How to update forum database from iPhone

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have a WordPress forum and I want to create an iPhone application that takes a photo and post the photo on the forum. Is it possible to access forum's database from iPhone?

I have some of basic knowledge how to send and receive information between iPhone and a web server.  I have done a couple of applications that sync with web server. I wrote php scripts to access MySQL database and send data back to device in XML format. But I am not sure I can still do this kinds of work with third party forums such as WordPass or any well known forum..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has RPC services, that you should be able to use.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support